# Template argument deduction not working as expected

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming

Why does the following print "Generic" instead of "const A &"? I surmised that a `dynamic_cast<>` would have done the trick to calling the first `f` but it doesn't. Why is this?

```
struct A {}; struct B : A {};

template <const A &>  void f()  { std::cout << "const A &"; }
template <typename T> void f(T) { std::cout << "Generic";   }

int main() {

   B b;

   f(dynamic_cast<const A &>(b)); // "Generic"

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first `f()` does not accept an argument, which leaves only the `f(T)` as a match.

Comment: Thanks. I'm still having problems with this but you answered the first and foremost question so I won't bombard you with a follow-up.

Comment: @typedeftypename, just post a new question. It will get more attention and I am sure someone will be able to help.